# SSH tunneling over Tor?

Tags: ssh

I am trying to create ssh tunnel over tor on Windows machine using Cygwin. I first start Tor service, tor.exe is running on local port 9151. But how to create the ssh tunnel? If i type `ssh user@xx.xx.xx -D 9151` it says that the address is already in use and it can not implement local forwarding.

What is the right way to implement ssh tunneling over tor to remote server?

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked in the past: [How can I anonymize my SSH traffic using the Tor network?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/123/how-can-i-anonymize-my-ssh-traffic-using-the-tor-network)

There are also some SSH-related details on the [Tor wiki](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO/Misc#SSH).

Alternatively, Googling something along the lines of "[using SSH over Tor](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=using%20ssh%20over%20tor&rls=com.microsoft:en-GB:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7SKPT_en&gfe_rd=cr&ei=YyCdVaWCFOSq8wedsYGYDw&gws_rd=ssl)" provides a lot of results, including a number of how-tos.