# Error OpenSSH over TAILS

Tags: tails, linux, debian, ssh, vps

Does anybody have an idea what wrong am I doing? So short, I've just launched TAILS OS and trying to connect to VPS over openSSH. With command `ssh -i /home/amnesia/Persistent/id_rsa root@11.11.11.11` But after that Error message comes along..

```
FATAL: Failed to determine SOCKS server. 
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Already tried to surf whole internet to find somebody with familiar issue, but no luck .. Any help would be very appreciated :)

Comment: Does the following command work with you: `ssh -o ProxyCommand='nc -x localhost:9150 %h %p' -i /home/amnesia/Persistent/id_rsa root@11.11.11.11`? See also https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/127/88